# MinGW doesn't like comments

Tags: c++, c, comments, codeblocks, mingw32

I have a compiling Problem using "code::blocks" on Windows 7. My C-code is:

```
//whatever
 int main(void){return 0;}
//this is blank line
```

The MinGW commandline is:

> gcc.exe -Wall  -g  -ansi    -c C:...\Test\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o

If i try to compile this, I get the error:

```
C:\...\Test\main.c|1|error: expected identifier or '(' before '/' token
```

(I wanted to post a picture here, but not enough reputation ...)

There are only 3 lines of code in my source file. (The last just contains `\0`, but I didn't know, how to add a blank line). I use `code::blocks` as IDE. I used `notepad++` to search for non-printable chars, but with no meaningful results. I use the `MinGW` compiler that is available as bundled download with code::blocks. I corrected the `"toolchain executables"` and the compiler worked fine until now.

It's not the first time I had this problem. I remember having it on another computer before and solved it by retyping the whole source file (which I don't want to do every time).

The way the error was provoked is just commenting and uncommenting code for a while (I tried out some things and commented previous tests away). And than, out of the blue, this error appeared.

Sorry, if my grammar is bad. English is not my mother tongue.

I appreciate any given help!
Thanks in advance,
Nils

Comment: "The last just contains `\0`" - are you sure? If it's really the NUL character, that's illegal. Did you mean a newline (`\n`) instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the compiler option `-ansi`.

ANSI C does not understand `//`.

From the [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html):

> **3.4 Options Controlling C Dialect**
>
> [...]
>
> **-ansi**
>
> In C mode, this is equivalent to -std=c90. In C++ mode, it is equivalent to -std=c++98.
>
> [...] For the C compiler, it disables recognition of C++ style ‘//’ comments [...]

Comment: That does it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Or, add the option `-std=c99`.

Answer (score 3):

In code blocks do this

Make sure that highlighted option is unchecked.(This is same as above ans. removing -ansi. option.)

`Settings->compiler`

[image: Settings->compiler]

Answer (score 0):

For compiling c use

```
/* C-style comments!
 */
```

Comment: @H2CO3 c99 is the default option, a different one could be set in project settings.

Comment: yay, but it's hard to know if OP doesn't post his command line (which he originally didn't).